# What is git doing with my generated files from ./autogen.sh and ./configure?

Tags: git, configure

The project I'm working on uses `autogen.sh` and `configure` to set up compilation, and these generate files such as `config.h` and others. Now, when generated, I would assume that these files would be untracked and so `git status` should list these files. However, doing so after running these two scripts actually produces this output:

```
owner@ubuntu:~/project$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

The `nothing to commit (working directory clean)` implies that nothing has changed since the last commit. Furthermore, it does not tell me that `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by X commits.`, meaning that no new commits have been made (confirmed by `git log`).

If these files aren't untracked and they have not been committed, how is git treating these files? I should mention that there are no `.gitignore` files anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git doesn't have any special magic for handling those files, though perhaps your project does hidden away somewhere else.  Check with `git status --ignored` to see if they are being ignored anyway.

If so, you should also check `.git/info/exclude`, and any global ignore configuration you have in git, to see if they are responsible for those files being ignored.

Comment: Ah, apparently there were exclude patterns in the `./git/info/exclude` file. Thanks!